# How to convert nested select query in linq?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, linq

how to convert nested select query to linq statment in asp.net mvc

```
select * from ProviderPostComments M where M.Id not in (
select c.Id from ProviderPostComments as c , BlockUsers as b 
where  (
(c.RequesterID = b.RequesterId and b.RequesterID= '9E58484C-D01C-49B0-8BCC-2C22EE468D8A')
or 
(c.RequesterID = b.ProviderId and b.ProviderId  = '9E58484C-D01C-49B0-8BCC-2C22EE468D8A')
)
and b.IsDeleted=0

)
```

Comment: Which query provider are you using? Entity Framework? What have you tried?

Comment: yes , entity freamwork

Comment: What version of EF? core or normal? Show us your entities

Comment: yes normal EF ` var query = db.ProviderComments.AsNoTracking()
                            .Include(arg => arg.Provider)
                            .Include(arg => arg.Provider.BlockUsers)
                            .Include(arg => arg.Requester.BlockUsers)
                            .Include(arg => arg.Post)
                         .Where(arg => !arg.IsDeleted && !arg.Post.IsDeleted) `

Comment: OK, so I've managed to establish you're using EF, not EFCore.. But that's about it. What version of EF? (Say a number like "6.4"). Show us your entities? (Edit the question to include code that looks like `class ProviderPostComment{ ... virtual ICollection<BlockUser> BlockUsers ...`)

Comment: Perhaps my [SQL to LINQ Recipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49245160/sql-to-linq-with-multiple-join-count-and-left-join/49245786#49245786) might help you.

Answer (score 0):

Hello below is a sample nested LINQ

you can modify that as you wish

```
yourlist.SelectMany(h => h.Itemtype)
      .Select(rt => rt.Item.Id)
      .Distinct()
      .ToArray();
```